# php query to database returning blank results

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, connection

---

### ----- UPDATED

Code works when I'm running it from my schools public_html folder.  However, when I create the exact same file, upload to my personal web server it does not work and only produces a blank screen.  Not exactly sure what this means, maybe that I don't have permissions?

Updated Code to reflect suggestions (still not working)

### -----------

Hi I'm a student learning to use php and postgres.  Currently I'm just trying to open a connection from my hosted website to my database on my school's server.  I'm getting a blank result with my following php file.

I put 'xxxxx' as the connection fields in order not to give away my username and password - the real file has the correct information.

My question is... is there anything wrong with this php file?

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>

<?php
$username = "xxxxx"
$password = "xxxxx";
$databasename = "xxxxx";
$hostname = "xxxxx";

$connection = pg_connect("host=$hostname dbname=$databasename user=$username password=$password") or die ("could not connect");

$query = "SELECT unit_name from units";

$result = pg_query($connection, $query) or die("ERROR: " . pg_last_error());

$row = 0;
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "$row[0]<br>\n"
};


pg_close($connection);
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i can't find declared variable $row in your code

Comment: adding row variable - still nothing displaying.

Comment: First of all, turn on error displaying in php. it will show you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `pg_fetch_row`
Try this

```
$query = "SELECT unit_name from units";

$result = pg_query($connection, $query) or die("ERROR: ".pg_last_error());

if(!result)
{
    echo "An error occurred.\n";
    exit;
} 

$data = [];
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
   $data[] = $row; 
}

foreach($data as $value)
{
   echo $value;
}
```

Comment: still a blank result.  i'm wondering if its the html tags causing problems?

Comment: Try `<h1>Test</h1>` Just after body start and before <?php

Comment: just ran the info.php test and it gave me back all the php information, so I know php is installed and work.  The <h1>Test</h1>  did not display anything on the page.

Comment: Remove all php code and just try html body and heading and check what it gives

Comment: Ok, it still doesn't display Test - which is odd.  Maybe because its a php file?

Comment: When I view the page source from my site it shows blank tags.  I'm wondering if this is sending the result to my database name + my username site location and not displaying it on the php page thats calling the connection and query

Comment: I think you are not run that file in which you are writing code.

Comment: hmm maybe, but my other php files work just fine.  Such as, displaying user inputted information or just echo statements.  I think its something in the php causing the entire thing to fail.

Answer (score 0):

This Code success on my side! try this.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("YourHostname", "Your Username", "YourPassword", "YourDBName");

// Check conn
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql="/*Your SQL CODE HERE*/";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
 echo "Success!";
} else{
 echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: I meant to put postgres as the search field for this.  This would differ a little because mines connecting to a Postgres server and not a MySQL